# PAM authentication not working in python

Tags: python, authentication

http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/athena/system/i386_deb50/os-ubuntu-9.04/usr/athena/share/doc/python-pam/examples/pamtest.py
This code is not working.

For the users present in the system too, it gives error as "Go away! (('Authentication failure', 7))

ANy idea?

Comment: This is referencing a file on your computer.

Comment: Yeah, Steve :|, do it.

Comment: Steve:  sorry, didnt notice that , my bad.

Comment: http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/athena/system/i386_deb50/os-ubuntu-9.04/usr/athena/share/doc/python-pam/examples/pamtest.py

Comment: The relevant line is here; `except PAM.error, resp:`

Comment: jonny- what amendments are required here?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the answer. This code will work only when you are logged in as root or you have run the code as sudo user. :-) This is because, only root has access to /etc/passwd.